# need syntax for multiple joins with embedded queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

M$ Access 2010

I have two tables CONTACT and  AAEmail_X

This works great

```
SELECT aa.[Contact ID], mm.Email AS [Personal Email]
FROM [CONTACT] AS aa
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT bb.[ClientID], bb.Email
FROM AAEmail_X AS bb
WHERE bb.Type = "Personal Email") AS mm
ON aa.[Contact ID] = mm.[ClientID];
```

note the embedded query contained within the parentheses.

Now I'd like to extend it to contain another embedded query

```
SELECT aa.[Contact ID], mm.Email AS [Personal Email], nn.Email AS [Business Email]
FROM ( [CONTACT] AS aa
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT bb.[ClientID], bb.Email
FROM AAEmail_X AS bb
WHERE bb.Type = "Personal Email") AS mm
ON aa.[Contact ID] = mm.[ClientID]  )
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT cc.[ClientID], cc.Email
FROM AAEmail_X AS cc
WHERE cc.Type = "Business Email") AS nn
ON aa.[Contact ID] = nn.[ClientID];
```

note the first join is enclosed within parantheses due to Access' quirky SQL implementation

This fails with Access prompting for a value to be manually entered for  "Query2.ClientID"

So I think I'm tangled up in parentheses hell. Can anyone spot what's wrong?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you started a bracket after the first FROM

```
SELECT aa.[Contact ID], mm.Email AS [Personal Email], nn.Email AS [Business Email]
FROM CONTACT AS aa
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT bb.[ClientID], bb.Email
        FROM AAEmail_X AS bb
        WHERE bb.Type = 'Personal Email'
    ) AS mm ON aa.[Contact ID] = mm.[ClientID]  

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT cc.[ClientID], cc.Email
        FROM AAEmail_X AS cc
        WHERE cc.Type = 'Business Email'
    ) AS nn ON aa.[Contact ID] = nn.[ClientID];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your parentheses are the problem...
Try

```
SELECT aa.[Contact ID], mm.Email AS [Personal Email], nn.Email AS [Business Email]
    FROM ( [CONTACT] AS aa
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT bb.[ClientID], bb.Email
        FROM AAEmail_X AS bb
        WHERE bb.Type = "Personal Email") AS mm
    ON aa.[Contact ID] = mm.[ClientID]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT cc.[ClientID], cc.Email
        FROM AAEmail_X AS cc
        WHERE cc.Type = "Business Email") AS nn
    ON aa.[Contact ID] = nn.[ClientID]
);
```

or

```
SELECT aa.[Contact ID], mm.Email AS [Personal Email], nn.Email AS [Business Email]
    FROM (( [CONTACT] AS aa
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT bb.[ClientID], bb.Email
        FROM AAEmail_X AS bb
        WHERE bb.Type = "Personal Email") AS mm
    ON aa.[Contact ID] = mm.[ClientID])
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT cc.[ClientID], cc.Email
        FROM AAEmail_X AS cc
        WHERE cc.Type = "Business Email") AS nn
    ON aa.[Contact ID] = nn.[ClientID]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Must have had some subtle misspelling or syntactical error.

```
SELECT aa.[Contact ID], mm.Email AS [Personal Email], nn.Email AS [Business Email]
FROM ( [CONTACT] AS aa
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bb.[ClientID], bb.Email FROM AAEmail_X AS bb WHERE bb.Type = "Personal     Email")  AS mm
ON aa.[Contact ID] = mm.[ClientID] )
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cc.[ClientID], cc.Email FROM AAEmail_X AS cc WHERE cc.Type = "Business Email")  AS nn
ON aa.[Contact ID] = nn.[ClientID];
```

Thanks to all who answered!  Stackoverflow rocks!

Thanks again,

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve